# How to setup a simple API key for use with a Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, api, soap, restful-authentication

I am currently writing a payment gateway integration for wordpress (simple redirect) and once finished I would like to list it for sale online for others to use.

The plugin will be listed in the wordpress extensions, and there will be a free version with all the basic functionality. The pro (paid) version will have further customisation to page styling etc.

So - I would like people to pay on a website for an API key for the pro version, and simply enable that functionality on their plugin by entering the key...

Can someone point me in the right direction as to where to start? 
Is there an open source framework for this already available? 
Do I learn RESTful/SOAP?

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to a 3rd Party solution, check out http://3scale.net. It will take care of letting you create a white-label page to assign/manage API keys, and let you set up metering too, if you'd like. I've used their Scala library with great success, but there is also a PHP library they provide that will do the trick for you.

https://github.com/3scale/3scale_ws_api_for_php/tree/master